# How to change layout in bootstrap

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to show my products in horizontal. In one line only three pics shown and 3 rows only 9 latest pics shown. How can I do this?

blade file:

```
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @foreach($data as $row)
            <div class="wpf-demo-4">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="Maecenas sodales tortor ac ligula ultrices dictum et quis urna.">  
                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="img-responsive" alt=" " style="width: 380px; height: 263px;" />
                    <div class="view-caption">
                        <p>{{ $row->name }}</p>
                    </div> 
                </a>            
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Post::all();
    return view('index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your blade to this: one `whole line` in top of foreach and `1/3` of each line in each foreach:

```
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="row"><!-- this changed -->
        @php($index = 0)
        @foreach($data as $row)
            @if($index < 9)
            <div class="wpf-demo-4 col-md-4"><!-- this line changed -->
                <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="Maecenas sodales tortor ac ligula ultrices dictum et quis urna.">  
                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="img-responsive" alt=" " style="width: 380px; height: 263px;" />
                    <div class="view-caption">
                        <p>{{ $row->name }}</p>
                    </div> 
                </a>            
            </div>
            @endif
            @php($index += 1)
        @endforeach
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

in your controller you can limit the collection that you are getting
like this:

```
$data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); //this line gets the posts record ordering by date
```

This last example looks like this:

[Example of display tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7lYC.png)

Comment: only 9 pics are not showing all pics which I added are showing

Comment: @programmer0001       i have been updated my answere, try this again

Comment: now it is showing only 8 old pics,,, I wants latest 9 pics

Comment: i have been updated my answer, don't forget to do what i wrote in my answer to your controller @programmer0001

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering the query and limiting the results to 9 or paginate.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
    return view('home')->with(['data' => $data]);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($data as $row)
        <div class="wpf-demo-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="Maecenas sodales tortor ac ligula ultrices dictum et quis urna.">  
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="img-responsive" alt=" " style="width: 380px; height: 263px;" />
                <div class="view-caption">
                    <p>{{ $row->name }}</p>
                </div> 
            </a>            
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

This last example looks like this:
[Example of display without pagination tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkfqH.png)

Or alternative paginated

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
    return view('home')->with(['data' => $data]);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="gallery-grids-row">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($data as $row)
        <div class="wpf-demo-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="jzBoxLink item-hover" title="Maecenas sodales tortor ac ligula ultrices dictum et quis urna.">  
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $row->image }}" class="img-responsive" alt=" " style="width: 380px; height: 263px;" />
                <div class="view-caption">
                    <p>{{ $row->name }}</p>
                </div> 
            </a>            
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    {{ $data->links() }}
</div>
```

This last example looks like this:
[Example of display tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8jGI.png)

Comment: in second method Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View:

Comment: Please, tell me if you have changed the query to the next one? $data = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9); Thank you.

Comment: yes,,, and if I use 2nd method  then its shows all data

Comment: Maybe I understand more your question, you want to return all posts from the controller to the view and then limited to the last most recent 9 on the view itself? Is that so? Not to paginate the results of 9 in 9 correct?

Comment: @programmer0001, i apologize, for not having correctly understood what I wanted to do, the answer chosen is the right one for you. A cordial greeting.